# How to change OutlinedButton border color?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Flutter widget, I tried to change the OutlineButton border color by using BorderSide(color : Colors.blue). The OutlineButton always with grey color border no matter which color is set, but width change is applicable.  How to change the OutlineButton border line color?

```
class OutlineButtonWidget extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
        child: OutlineButton(
            onPressed: null,
            borderSide: BorderSide(
                width: 5.0,
                color: Colors.blue,
                style: BorderStyle.solid,
            ),
            child: Text('outline button')
            ),
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 147, accepted):

Use the`style` property:

```dart
OutlinedButton(
  onPressed: () {},
  child: Text('Outlined button'),
  style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
    side: BorderSide(width: 5.0, color: Colors.blue),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 26):

**use *style* property**

```
   style: ButtonStyle(
                    side: MaterialStateProperty.all(BorderSide(
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        width: 1.0,
                        style: BorderStyle.solid)))
```

---

**or try this both work**

```
style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
                          side: BorderSide(
                            width: 5.0,
                            color: Colors.blue,
                            style: BorderStyle.solid,
                          ),
                        ),
            child: Text('outline button')
            )
```

---

```
OutlinedButton(
                style: ButtonStyle(
                    side: MaterialStateProperty.all(BorderSide(
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        width: 1.0,
                        style: BorderStyle.solid))),
                onPressed: () {},
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Align(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding:
                            const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12.0),
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.clear,
                          size: 24,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text("Clear")
                  ],
                ))
```

result may like this
[image]

Answer (score 10):

I was getting 'OutlineButton' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Use OutlinedButton instead. See
the migration guide in flutter.dev/go/material-button-migration-guide).

Before migration code:

```
child: OutlineButton(
    onPressed: onPressed,
    child: CustomText(
      text,
      style: TextStyle(
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
          fontSize: 14,
          color: Colors.black),
    ),
    color: Colors.orange,
    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.amber),
  ),
```

After migration code:

```
child: OutlinedButton(
    onPressed: onPressed,
    child: CustomText(
      text,
      style: TextStyle(
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
          fontSize: 14,
          color: Colors.black),
    ),
    style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(backgroundColor: Colors.orange, side: BorderSide(color: Colors.amber)),
  ),
```

Here is official ref of backgroundColor and color properties:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ButtonStyle/backgroundColor.html

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialButton/color.html

Comment: This worked, Thanks!

style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(side: BorderSide(color: Colors.amber)),

Answer (score 9):

Style property will work

```
OutlineButton(
            onPressed: (){},
            style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
                          side: BorderSide(
                            width: 5.0,
                            color: Colors.blue,
                            style: BorderStyle.solid,
                          ),
                        ),
            child: Text('outline button')
            ),
        ),
```

Comment: 'OutlineButton' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Use OutlinedButton instead.

Answer (score 5):

[Flutter's documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/OutlinedButton-class.html) says that you need to define both shape and side properties

> Unlike TextButton or ElevatedButton, outline buttons have a default ButtonStyle.side which defines the appearance of the outline. Because the default side is non-null, it unconditionally overrides the shape's OutlinedBorder.side. In other words, to specify an outlined button's shape and the appearance of its outline, both the ButtonStyle.shape and ButtonStyle.side properties must be specified.

So, you need to pass

```
child: OutlinedButton(
  onPressed: () {},
  style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
    ),
    side: const BorderSide(
      width: 5.0,
      color: Colors.blue,
    ),
  ),
  child: const Text('outline button'),
),
```

Answer (score 2):

### Theming

I wanted to avoid manually theming each `OutlinedButton`, and use theming instead.

You can do this with `ThemeData`'s `outlinedButtonTheme`:

```dart
   final color = ...;
   ThemeData(
    ...
    outlinedButtonTheme: OutlinedButtonThemeData(
        style: ButtonStyle(
          side: MaterialStateProperty.all(const BorderSide(color: color)),
          // surfaceTintColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.blue),
        )),
  );
```

[image: Animation using Flutter hot reload to change border style]